# Controller/Action not found although physically present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My attempt to make a `new`-action which gives the user a form and a `create`-action to process it fails with the error message `.

**View:** app/views/studios/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @studio, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:** app/controllers/studio_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @studio = Studio.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @studio }
  end
end

def create
  # TODO
end
```

**Route:** config/routes.rb

```
get 'studios/new' => 'studios#new', :as => 'new_studio'
```

On attempting to visit `http://localhost:3000/studios/new`, I am presented with the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"studios"}
```

As you can see, the `create`-action is present in the `studios`-controller. Why is it failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's failing because you don't have route defined for the `create` action.  You have a `get` action defined for the `new` action only.

Update your routes file to add a `post` route to the `create` action as:

```
post 'studios/create' => 'studios#create'
```

Or, you could choose to use resourceful routing and update your routes file as:

```
resources :studios, only: [ :new, :create ]
```

This will define the `new` and `create` route for your `studio` resource.  To see the generated routes you can run `rake routes`.

Comment: Really, are the controllers themselves unaware of their own routes? In PHP Symphony you can refer to actions without declaring them in the routing. Is this not possible in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

The rails form helper, given the instance variable `@studio`, asks for the instance variable via the `new` action, and, upon clicking save, calls the `create` action to validate and save this new instance. It's failing because rails cannot find the action to submit the object to.

Try adding `resources :studios` for RESTful routes in `config/routes.rb` (index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy) automagically routing to actions with the same name in the `app/controllers/studio_controller.rb`

Try visiting the docs for form helpers here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object for a more in depth explaination.